# How to install tkinter onto pycharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tk-toolkit, python-3.6

I've been playing around with tkinter a lot at my school using pycharm, but when i go home and use the pycharm on my pc, the module is not installed for tkinter. I can't seem to find how to install it. I am running python 3.6. I do not have python running on cmd.exe. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

install Packages : 'future' import tkinter

Comment: could you clarify this a bit

Answer (score 1):

just open terminal and do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

restart your pycharm.

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Just import Tkinter with lowercase t: `import tkinter as tk`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command line:

```
pip install python-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, you may need to uninstall and reinstall Pycharm. I had this problem on Linux Mint 20, and the issue was I was using the Flathub version of Pycharm. I uninstalled, and downloaded pycharm from the website, installed through terminal and suddenly everything works.

Comment: Not sure this advice is relevant as OP is on Windows not linux.